# Make cookie presistent even after browser shutdown/restart using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, asp.net-web-api

I am using Angular for my project, and got into a problem with authentication. On successfull authentication user retrive a token from server, and as long user have this token he can access all the places where he need authentication (i thought its a best way to do this since i use MVC web API as backend, and i dont have sessions). Everything works fine, until i close down my browser, and start it up again $cookieStore and $cookies are empty after restart.

Does anyone have any idea how to make cookie presistent, or are there any smarter way of doing this?

Ive created a test controller with a testview where i have 2 buttons which set and load $cookie before restart it works, if i open a new window while the other one is still up its works too, but as soon i close everything down, coockies is empty.

```
    $scope.Set = function () {

    $scope.LoadedData = "test";
    $cookies.myFavorite = 'oatmeal';

}


$scope.Load = function () {

    var b = $cookies.myFavorite;
    console.log("testasdasd" + $cookies);

    $scope.LoadedData = $cookies.myFavorite;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 types of cookies: session cookie and persistent cookie.

- Session cookie is in memory and only survives until you close the browser.
- Persistent cookie will be saved into disc and will be expired based on the `Expires` property.

The decision to save the cookie as session or persistent is server side, not your client side javascript.

When you use .NET Forms authentication, you can use `FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie` to create a cookie, the second parameter determines if this is a session or a persistent cookie.

Comment: can i use FormsAuthentication even if i dont use forms authentication?

Comment: @Timsen: In asp.net framework, Form authentication is actually a module registered in the pipeline to intercept requests before they reach your Handlers. I think it's possible, but you have to implement it yourself. You have to write your own module and register it with the framework and intercept the requests yourself.

Comment: @Timsen: Why not just enable it by specifying a configuration in web.config?

Answer (score 1):

I know this question was already answered, but actually you CAN manage cookies persistence client side. Just [$cookieStore](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore).

**Persistent cookie:**

```
// from your controller
$cookieStore.put('auth_token', token);
// in your module
$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = $cookieStore.get('auth_token');
```

In the module, we are telling angular that we want to use this session everytime any page of  our website it's loaded.

**EDIT:** You may be interested in [HTML5 localstorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage) instead of cookies.